# Reference the result of a multiply op?

Tags: x86, masm

Im working on a homework assignment that requires I take an elapsed time, and format it in a few different ways.

My current issue at hand is referencing the result of a multiplication.

```
mov ax, 3600 ;Copy 3600D to ax for multiplication...
mul Hours; After this, DX:AX have the result...

add TotalSeconds, dx:ax <- This is incorrect according to MASM
```

TotalSeconds is defined as `TotalSeconds DD 0`

I'm not 100% sure how to reference the concatenation of the two registers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `add TotalSeconds, dx:ax` to

```
add word ptr TotalSeconds, ax
adc word ptr TotalSeconds+2, dx
```

Please read the CPU manual (either from Intel or from AMD) to see what instructions and operands are valid.